# Name of single sample multinomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

The Binomial$(n, p)$ distribution is called "Bernoulli distribution" with parameter $p$ in the special case $n=1$. Many properties of the Binomial are derived from the fact that the sum of $n$ i.i.d. copies of a Bernoulli$(p)$ random variable is again Binomial distributed $n, p$.

I was wondering if there is also a specific name for the multinomial distribution with $n=1$ (besides the generic term "discrete distribution")?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called the categorical distribution (among other things).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution

This article mentions the following names: categorical, multinoulli, generalized Bernoulli

Comment: Thanks for the nice and compact answer. I quite like 'multinoulli' ;-).

Comment: @MichaelM, the next step will be renaming Jacob Bernoulli to "Binoulli" - disambiguating the two  ;-)

Comment: Haha, will try to use this the next time